# The constraints in my tableview isn't working on my view objects. Any reason why?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I have downloaded data from a URL and wanted to display it in a table view. I've gotten the data to populate, but I can get the constraints to work on the view objects in my table view.

Here is a complete picture of my storyboard :

[image: Storyboard]

But this is what I end up getting in my simulator :

[image]

Does anyone understand the reason why I am getting these constraint problems? Thank you.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pictures.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:  IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"PictureCell") as! PictureCellTableViewCell
    
    cell.likeLabel.text = String(pictures[indexPath.row].likes)
    cell.tagsLabel.text = pictures[indexPath.row].tags
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What you are returning in the tableview's delegate method:
func tableView(UITableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath) -> CGFloat

Comment: @NajeeburRehman I am only using func cellForRowAt and numberOfRowsPerSection. Is that a func I should add?

Comment: Implement UITableViewDelegate protocol and make sure to set your class as tableView delegate where your are conforming to that protocol. And implement the heightForRowAt method to specify any specific height or just return UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Comment: @NajeeburRehman thank you, kind sir.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helps.

Comment: A few more thoughts, maybe something could help. (Keep in mind I *never* use storyboards.) First, thanks for posting a link to what you are getting - but what are you expecting? Expecting that's different? Second, is the result any different in a different "device"? (Placing that in quotes because you haven't really said you've tried it on (a) a "real" device or (b) in any other simulated divice.)

Comment: @dfd firstly, I was expecting both labels to show in my table view cell, but the cell wasn't tall enough to display both labels. I had to implement protocol heightforrowat. And no I haven't tried it on a real device. I'm having issues with constraints currently.

Comment: @NajeeburRehman do you have an idea why my constraints on the stack view aren't working? Should I implement those constraints in a different way?

Comment: What unusal behaviour you are getting regarding constraints ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to resolve the constraint issues you're having. Starting from the beginning....

**Step 1:** Add labels to cell.
[image]

**Step 2:** Embed labels in stack view.
[image]

**Step 3:** Pin all edges of stack view to cell.
[image]

**Step 4:** Almost there, we just need to resolve content hugging priority issues with labels...
[image]]

**Step 5:** Lower the bottom label's `Vertical Content Hugging Priority` to be a smaller value than the top label. With this in place, both labels won't have to fight over who should be prioritized. The bottom label now has a lower vertical content hugging priority so it will allow itself to adjust its vertical height. In other words, the label  Because of how `AutoLayout` works and cell resizing, this is required.

[image]

Using storyboards as an intro-iOS developer is a good starting point to visualize constraints, as constraint issues can be difficult to resolve in `UIKit` when done programatically.

As you progress in your understandings though you'll eventually move away from storyboards all together and layout your views programmatically.

You could also opt to learn SwiftUI and see how dealing with constraints is not as an issue as in UIKit.